# Working with data inside the Hash

Tags: ruby, database, hash

I am trying to build a system, for Personal Finance Management, with this I hope to learn Ruby.

I created a Stock < Asset.
This has all the information regarding the Asset (current spot price, etc).
And I have my Profile, where I am able to add the Asset to my Balance with the buying_price, quantities, dates, etc.

I would like to show_assets_by_code, and when I run this method, I want the system to go trough my Assest, and then classify this by code, and sum the Quantity, get the average_price with cost included. And return this: [asset, average_price_with_cost, total_quantity]

Right now I am able to group the assets:

```
{"RNGO11"=>
  [{:quantity=>10,
    :buying_price=>75.0,
    :cost=>16.91,
    :date=>2016-09-05 18:06:06 -0300,
    :code=>"RNGO11",
    :asset_id=>18563448},
   {:quantity=>100,
    :buying_price=>75,
    :cost=>16.91,
    :date=>"16/4/2015",
    :code=>"RNGO11",
    :asset_id=>18563448},
   {:quantity=>100,
    :buying_price=>77,
    :cost=>16.91,
    :date=>"16/4/2016",
    :code=>"RNGO11",
    :asset_id=>18563448}],
 "BRCR11"=>
  [{:quantity=>100,
    :buying_price=>75,
    :cost=>16.91,
    :date=>2016-09-05 18:06:06 -0300,
    :code=>"BRCR11",
    :asset_id=>18563316}]}
```

How can I get the information, and work with the data inside the Hash for each group?

I want the output:

```
[RNGO11, quantity: 210, average_price: 76.19]
[BRCR11, quantity: 100, average_price: 75.17]
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data.map do |key, values|
  quantity = values.map { |entry| entry[:quantity] }.reduce(:+)
  average_price = values.map { |entry| entry[:buying_price] + entry[:cost] }.reduce(:+).to_f / values.size
  { code: key, quantity: quantity, average_price: average_price }
end
```

Let me know if this works for you
Edit: added cost into consideration

Comment: Almost there!! The average_price must be: for each asset:
 sum((buying_price * quantity) + cost) / total_quantity

I am not able to do this! How?

Comment: `assets_by_group = balance.assets.group_by{|asset| asset[:code]}
   assets_by_group.map do |asset, values|
   quantity = values.map { |entry| entry[:quantity] }.reduce(:+)
   total_spent = values.map { |entry| entry[:buying_price].to_f * entry[:quantity].to_f + entry[:cost].to_f }.reduce(:+).to_f
   average_price = total_spent / quantity`
But it don`t work when I sell... the math will change... but Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Pawel Duda, I got it right!

```
    transactions = balance.assets
    assets_by_group = transactions.group_by{|asset| asset[:code]}
    assets_by_group.map do |asset, transactions|
    sum_quantity = 0
    asset_average_price = 0
            transactions.each do |transaction|
                quantity = transaction[:quantity]
   ## :average_price = price + (cost / (quantity).abs) for each transaction.
                average_price = transaction[:average_price] 
                asset_average_price = ( average_price * quantity + asset_average_price * sum_quantity) / (sum_quantity + quantity) if quantity > 0
   ## Sells (quantity < 0) do not change asset_average_price.
                sum_quantity += quantity
            end
    { code: asset, quantity: sum_quantity, average_price: asset_average_price}
    end
```

If anyone wants to improve this code, I will be glad! 
I smell improvements but not able to spot it. Looks not DRY... not readable.
But hey, it is working for buying and selling the assets. (According to what I will have to declare for Income Federal Taxes (Brazil).

Comment: Good that you found a solution (now mark one of the answers, such that the question is seen as "answered"). But please use other places for code review (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?) And problems like yours are an invitation to fall in love with a testing framework like `minitest`.

Comment: @Felix I think I did mark Pawel Duda's answer, not? (Is it the green check?)
I will check this codereview place ;)
Not sure what you meant by minitest...